# How to convert byte[] to bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap, byte, bitmapdata

I want to share bitmap between server and client. I've tried a lot, but I've had problems with all the way the bottom part of the image missing.

1. First way:

   ```
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(800, 450);

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(readBuffer))
            {
                bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
            }
   ```
2. Second way:

   ```
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(readBuffer))
            {
                bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
                //bmp = Image.FromStream(ms) as Bitmap;
            }
   ```
3. This way, the image wasn't converted properly.

   ```
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(800, 450, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

            BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(
                                 new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                                 ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

            Marshal.Copy(readBuffer, 0, bmpData.Scan0, readBuffer.Length);

            bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
   ```

How can I properly convert to a bitmap where the bottom part has not disappeared?
This is the code I used to convert the bitmap to byte.

```
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
        panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height));

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bmp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
            sendBuffer = stream.ToArray();
        }
        Array.Resize(ref sendBuffer, 1024*4);
```

Comment: If the bottom part disappears then you aren't sending enough data. For example if you had 10kb bitmap, and used a 3kb buffer but only did two read/write cycle the image would look like the bottom third was missing. Check the logic behind all your buffers/anything that reads or writes the image data to see if it is stopping too soon or forgetting to flush

Comment: Why are you resizing the array? It should be exactly as long as the stream.

Comment: After writing the buffer to the networkstream, I flush() the networkstream and initialize sendBuffer to 0. And when initializing to 0, I reseize() because for loop is repeated for sendBuffer size 1024*4.

Comment: Use the second code block (2) and don't dispose the MemoryStream as long as you need to use the Bitmap.  Why do you need a Bitmap object if the aim is to stream it to an endpoint?

Comment: If you have the file as bytes, just send the bytes. Don't bother making a `Bitmap` object out of it. That just pollutes your local memory since Bitmaps are unmanaged GDI+ objects.